# Dynamic QML, edit attributes of instance in JS

Tags: javascript, qml

I'm creating dynamic instances of objects with JS and try to set attributes while creation. I tried it first with width.

```
var component;
var gauge;

function createVerticalGauge() {
    component = Qt.createComponent("VerticalBarGauge.qml");
    if (component.status == Component.Ready)
        finishCreation();
    else
        component.statusChanged.connect(finishCreation);
}

function finishCreation() {
    if (component.status == Component.Ready) {
        gauge = component.createObject(root, {"x": 100, "y": 100});
        gauge.width = 300;
        if (gauge == null) {
            // Error Handling
            console.log("Error creating object");
        }
    } else if (component.status == Component.Error) {
        // Error Handling
        console.log("Error loading component:", component.errorString());
    }
}
```

But the attribute is not changed by the javascript. No error or warning appears while compilation.

This is the QML of the Object that is created by the javascript:

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4


Item {

    Rectangle {
        id: rev
        width: 100
        height: 80
        color: "transparent"
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top

        Gauge {
            id: revgauge
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 10
            orientation : Qt.Horizontal
            tickmarkStepSize : 5000
            minimumValue: 0
            maximumValue: 10000

            //value: Dashboard.revs
            Behavior on value {
                NumberAnimation {
                    duration: 5
                }
            }
            Text {
                font.pixelSize: (parent.height / 3)
                anchors.top : parent.top
                font.bold: true
                font.family: "Eurostile"
                color: "white"
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            }
              style: GaugeStyle {
                valueBar: Rectangle {
                   implicitWidth:  rev.height /3
                    color: Qt.rgba(revgauge.value / revgauge.maximumValue, 0, 1 - revgauge.value / revgauge.maximumValue, 1)
                }
            }
      }
    }
}
```

And how can I change the attribute of a object after it has been created. E.g. I want to change the location or the color of the object.

Comment: I think you are confusing, the code works correctly what is happening is that you are changing the width of the item, but not the width of the Rectangle so you do not observe the visual change.

Comment: How can I Change the width of the rectancle?

Comment: Use this VerticalBarGauge.qml: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/88cdfae1f0f1f147a926ed0c79b057b3